# changing wallpapers automatically in android

Tags: android

i am new to android programming and want to develop an application similar to vista where the wallpaper changes automatically , so how should i go about it, please could someone guide me on it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use the Wallpaper Manager Api : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html

Here is a related tutorial : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/SetWallpaperActivity.html

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you will have to use the [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) class which provides the neccesarry methods to do so.

Also, don't forget to add the SET_WALLPAPER  permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
</manifest>
```

**Edit:** take a look of the example that Ravi Vyas gave you... I didn't know about it and it looks pretty useful.